# Replace pi value in Python Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extremely new to python & learning on my own.
I found myself in a strange situation with the below code.

```
import math
math.pi = 1
```

Now how can revert to the original value of pi ?

Comment: Why would you ever want to reassign the value of math.pi?

Comment: simply type `exit()` -))

Comment: `math.pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795` Is that far enough? ;)

Comment: Did you exit and try again? Also, don't do such things! :P

Comment: Does Python not have checks to disallow assigning values to system variables ? Is'nt this a big "minus"

Comment: Only it rare cases. Sometimes it might make sense to override them.

Comment: I did not get any solution to work in python3. Sorry for the confusing. I deleted my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution. Although I'm pretty sure it's considered an unreliable hack, it does work. If you remove `'math'` from `sys.modules` it will reload properly. The dictionary `sys.modules` contains a lot of system information, and is most likely not meant to be edited. But on the other hand, the same goes for the value of pi.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> math.pi=1
>>> math.pi
1
>>> sys.modules.pop('math')
<module 'math' (built-in)>
>>> math.pi
1
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>>
```

Since i do not trust the stability of this solution, I'll provide my Python version for future reference: 3.5.3. I don't know if there's a point i providing "the right solution" to a problem that should never occur.

Answer (score 0):

The math module in python has various functions and constants predefined to make the code easier in terms of its complexity.
It is advised not to redefine the value of such constants as it may create problems with your program at runtime. Second, it does not make sense redefining the value of a constant, does it?

If at all you need store some value for later user, create a separate variable for that and use it later. Example :- a=1 (This creates a variable named a which has the value 1)